# New Pull Request Target Branch Not Default Error TF401175

Tags: azure-devops

When I am creating a new pull request the target branch is not using the default and is being set to a branch that no longer exists. Currently the master branch is set as the default and compare branch. When I create a new pull request on this repo I get the following error.  This does not happen to any other user in my organization either.

TF401175:The version descriptor <Branch: release/S133 > could not be resolved to a version in the repository Oasis

Comment: I've got the same issue, have you had any luck finding a fix?

Comment: Hi, I have added an answer, please check if it works on your side and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below steps:

1. **Restore the deleted branch:** Go to the branches list and search the deleted branch name, find the deleted branch and restore it like below:
   [image]
2. **Reset default branch.** Go to the branches list and set the branch you want to set it as default and compare again.
3. Then delete the branch you don't need it anymore. (Not required)
4. **Create a pull request again**.

Comment: I feel like there's more to this. I have same situation. But when I view Branches, "master" is clearly the default. However, when I create a new PR the target branch defaults to this very old branch that I have deleted and restored. So it does not appear that changing "default branch" actually changes the default target for New Pull Request.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue for me - are there other alternatives?

Comment: This worked when I set the restored branch to `Compare` and `Default`, then switched them back to `master`.

Answer (score 1):

*Based off of Doris Lv's Answer in this thread*

It's required to set Compare ***before*** Default, because there appears to be a bug with simply setting default first.

Please try the steps below:

1. Restore the deleted branch: Go to the branches list and search the deleted branch name, find the deleted branch and restore it. (Click the dots menu, select 'restore branch')
2. Set the newly restored branch first as "Compare" branch, and then "Default" branch, again from the dots menu.
3. Set the default branch as "Compare" branch, and then "Default" branch, again from the dots menu.
4. Delete the newly restored branch if you don't need it anymore. (Not required)
5. Create a pull request again.

Comment: What if you don't know the name of the deleted branch? This devops situation was setup before I was in this company.

Comment: It's in the initial error, like in the original post here: "TF401175:The version descriptor <Branch: release/S133 >" the branch is "release/S133"

Comment: I solved this by using another random branch and moving Compare and Default to that one, then going back to my main branch and setting Compare _then_ Default.

Comment: @MattM Glad that worked! I tried this at the time, and it did not. So i'm happy the functionality is slightly less broken now!